# Behavior Space syntax error

Tags: netlogo

I know this could be redundant to previous questions, but still, I need some help.

What I want to do is to exporting some data(specific agent) to R.

Since agentset is not a valid format for using package "RNetLogo",

I may as well use Behavior space.

The problem is the command (`ask turtle 0 [show [who] of closest-turtle`)is not workable and give error message (`"Experiment aborted due to syntax error: Expected reporter.`). However this command works fine in console.

My question is,
1. what is this error message mean and how can I fix it : 2. Is it possible to export specific agentset(with given condition) using package RNetLogo, and how.

Thank you for reading all this

Comment: A reporter should not start with `ask`. In NetLogo console, try something like `show [_here is your reporter_]`. BTW, I don't think RNetLogo and Behavior space have different requirements here.

Comment: I see, thanks, and one more thing, do you know how to export R's data to NetLogo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have defined `closest-turtle`, a reporter that BehaviorSpace would accept would be

```
[[who] of closest-turtle] of turtle 0
```

I assume that `closest-turtle` would be given by something like

```
to-report closest-turtle 
  report min-one-of other turtles [distance myself] 
end
```

Comment: I haven't thought of changing the order; That works Thank you very much~!:)